# Discord.py issues with copying bulk messages

Tags: python, discord.py

For context, I've created a discord bot for a server with myself and my friends.

Part of what I want this bot to do is be able to copy all the messages in a channel for backup purposes, as some of the channels have things we don't want to ever lose.

I've gotten it to copy messages, but it's having issues with copying many messages in a row.

Here's the code:

```py
@client.command()
async def MessageCopy(ctx, comeFrom, goTo):
    attachments = []
    aafile = None
    fromChannel = client.get_channel(int(comeFrom))
    toChannel = client.get_channel(int(goTo))
    async for message in fromChannel.history(oldest_first=True, limit=None):
        if not message.attachments == None:
            for file in message.attachments:
                aafile = await file.to_file()
                attachments.append(aafile)
        try:
            await toChannel.send(content=message.clean_content, file=aafile)
        except:
            continue
        attachments = []
        aafile = None
```

client is defined as

```py
commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", case_insensitive=True)
```

The bot gets caught at the same message each time, there's nothing special about the message, and it doesn't throw an error, it just quietly stops copying. If it matters, it's the 9639th message in the channel that it fails to copy.

**EDIT:** I ran another channel through it, it stopped quietly again, this time on the 9758th message.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a fix/workaround.

Turns out it might have been

```py
aafile = file.to_file()
```

that was causing it to stop copying, that code would cause and error and it would quietly stop.

So I changed the code around that to:

```py
for file in message.attachments:
    try:
        aafile = file.to_file()
        attachments.append(aafile)
    except:
        continue
```